# Custom Facebook Tab not rendering on mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I know there are other heavily answered questions out there for this, but I'm posting my specific configuration to see if maybe someone can tell me that I have an error.

My app is loading just fine on desktop, but I'm getting an error "The page you requested was not found" in my mobile browser.

**Facebook Canvas**
Canvas Page: https://apps.facebook.com/hiwayfcu-hockey
Secure Canvas URL: https://hiwayfcu.wpengine.com/redirect/?fb
Mobile Site URL: https://hiwayfcu.wpengine.com/redirect/?fb

**Website**
Site URL: http://hiwayfcu.wpengine.com/
*Mobile Site URL is no longer a field for this platform, as indicated by older discussions. Note, however, that my website is responsive so it should work for any browser size.*

**Page Tab**
Secure Page Tab URL: https://hiwayfcu.wpengine.com/

The code inside of my redirect page:

```
<script>top.location="https://www.facebook.com/hiwayfcu?sk=app_1154426381277023&ref=ts"</script>
```

This page was set up via Wordpress. I've seen some other reports that perhaps the redirection between Wordpress and FB doesn't work well, but I'm hoping that's an issue of the past.

Comment: I have been having the same issue and eventually found this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/ From what I can tell, facebook stopped the redirection of Canvas pages to mobile url (for some security reason), and now you have to ask them specifically to enable a workaround for your app. I have just asked them to implement the workaround for my app, but haven't heard back yet - I hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I just tried it out - fingers crossed!

Comment: Hey, @PaulFrench - have you heard anything back? I haven't. :/

Comment: No nothing sorry. I've almost given up on getting it to work :(

Comment: "As you can imagine there are thousands of apps that are affected by this issue and it is taking some time to work through the backlog of applications that have asked for asked to be added to the workaround." What a bummer! My temporary app will be irrelevant by the time they get around to it.

Comment: Still not fixed for all apps :(