# Unable to access Facebook app on mobile, gives "The page you requested was not found"

Tags: facebook, canvas

We recently created a HTML5/JS game for an Australian non-profit and set it up as a Facebook canvas app. But no one can access it from a mobile device.

The game works fine on desktop AND mobile when accessed directly via the URL (deadlychoicesgame.com)

It also works fine on desktop when accessed on apps.facebook.com.

But when trying to access the game through apps.facebook.com on mobile the user gets error "The page you requested was not found". This happens on both the mobile browser and native Facebook app (see screenshots below).

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue before with their own apps? If so what was the cause and/or solution?

Google turns up not much valuable insight. Some people have said they have contacted Facebook, but I can't see anywhere I would do that.

Everything is setup correctly in the app settings. The game is on https, has url & mobile url, has a canvas page (apps.facebook.com/deadlychoices), went through app review and was approved, and is live/public.

If anyone has any clues or ideas I would love to hear them. Even if it's just a way to contact Facebook and alert them about this potential issue.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Search developers.facebook.com/bugs . It is a know bug

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37303001/custom-facebook-tab-not-rendering-on-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who commented. Via your comments I have found it is a known bug and Facebook has implemented a workaround here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/